# Error Incomprehensible in Xml file Multiple Anontations

Tags: xml, spring

I get this error with my project in Eclipse into my XML files :

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://
     www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the 
     document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not 
     <xsd:schema>.
```

When i write just a space then save the file, the error desapear but after while it returns again. Any Aidea? Thank you

---

This is the content of my XML file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />   
    <context:component-scan base-package="gestion.delegation.controller" />
    <bean       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="AddUserValidator" class="gestion.delegation.validator.AddUserValidator" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Could you provide the content of the file that is experiencing the problem?

Comment: Ok i post the content of xml file above.

Comment: When I get weird errors about the schema I remove the versions numbers for the xsd files. What happens if you try that?

Comment: I have seen this error with IntelliJ, and to fix it there I needed to add *.xsd to the list of resources. I don't recall if this needs to be done for Eclipse. Have you tried it with the STS?

Comment: Even if i delete the number version the error still appears. I wanna understand : is the number version of the schema location must be the same as the version of Spring? here i use spring 3.0.5

Comment: Okay I think I resolve the problem; the word bean missed in the first line, this is it:

**<beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"**

I wish the error will not show again :/

Comment: I plugged the sample config into an XML editing tool and the validated it against the 3.0 schema and it passed. I did have to add the -3.0 to the spring-mvc. When I left the version off of spring-mvc it would not validate because it was pulling in two different versions for all of the XSDs.

Comment: The solution that i mentioned above about ':bean' dosen't work too, and when i add -3.0 to spring-mvc nothing is changed but the progect works as well, I just wanted to have a clean project!  Thank you